# How do I edit text in Cyrillic / Russian on OpenBSD?

Tags: character-encoding, input-method

I'm trying to make it possible to easily edit text in Cyrillic / Russian on a remote OpenBSD 5.2 amd64.

I'm using [`emacs-21.4p18-no_x11`](http://OpenBSD.SU/ports/editors/emacs21,no_x11,-main), which doesn't show any Cyrillic characters whatsoever when I try opening up a file with a `windows-1251` encoding (instead showing question marks and sometimes even randomly mangling the file when a save is attempted), unless I start it as `env LANG=bg_BG.CP1251 emacs` (for some reason, there's no `ru_RU.CP1251` in [`/usr/share/locale/`](http://OpenBSD.SU/src/share/locale/)) and PuTTY to `Win1251 (Cyrillic)`; however, this only works in displaying the characters, not for typing any characters — switching the local keyboard to Russian and typing into emacs causes various random internal commands to be executed, even though quitting emacs and using [`cat(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/cat.1) works without any issues for Russian input (which could then be opened up in emacs and copy-pasted from the temp file to the real one, which is very cumbersome and unproductive).

(FWIIW, I've also tried [`mg(1)`](http://OpenBSD.SU/src/usr.bin/mg/tutorial), but it shows up Russian characters as `\315` etc, and doesn't let you type in Russian, either.)

- If the files I'm editing are `nginx.conf`, is there a way to automatically specify the encoding for emacs?  All the [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) examples appear to start with a `mode`, but there's no mode for `nginx.conf`.
- How do I make emacs / mg load files in either `windows-1251` or `koi8-r`, and show them in `UTF-8`?
- How do I make emacs / mg accept Cyrillic input?

Comment: What does the first character in the modeline show when you load the file? Did you try `revert-buffer-with-coding-system`? I use phonetic (translit) when I type in Russian. That is I use `set-input-method` and choose `cyrillic-translit` (easier for me, because I don't know Russian keyboard key locations, but there are other input methods, you should be also able to emulate ЙЦУКЕН if you like. Also, Emacs 21 is really old... it's from something like 7 years ago, maybe even more...

Comment: Actually, Emacs 21.4 was released in 2005...

Comment: I don't have Russian letters on my keyboard, but I still seem to blindly remember where they're supposed to be (outside of the punctuation, apparently).

Comment: @wvxvw, yes, it appears to be the less bloated version, so, it's still available in all recently OpenBSD releases.

Comment: If you set input method to `cyrillic-jis-russian` you will be typing in ЙЦУКЕН layout, except, you won't need to send Cyrillic over the wire (which I suspect to be the problem). This is at least worth checking out. I would still recommend updating Emacs to a newer version. If there's something you don't need in it, I'd try to disable it during compile instead of using something that is known to have lots of bugs fixed over the last decade.

Comment: @wvxvw, I think I'd rather prefer to send Cyrillic over the wire; I don't have any issues with Cyrillic on my local machine.

Comment: Trying the input method helps diagnose the problem. The problem can be that you can send Cyrillic, but you can't display it, or you can display, but can't send. Also, you didn't say whether you tried to revert buffer while specifying the coding system.

Comment: The corruption doesn't happen all the time; today, it happened again just once; after which I've re-specified the koi8-r encoding; and copy-pasted the affected line, and it seems to have fixed it.  I think by default emacs maps some kind of commands to Russian input, so, I cannot type anything in Russian within emacs at all, but, again, it works in cat just fine.